# numpy remove column by different value in batch

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to ask how numpy remove columns in batch by list.
The value in the list corresponds to the batch is different from each other.

I know this problem can use the for loop to solve, but it is too slow ...

Can anyone give me some idea to speed up?

array (batch size = 3):

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

remove index in the list (batch size = 3)

```
[[2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 6], [0, 1, 5]]
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 5, 6], [0, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is 2d, and the indexing removes equal number of elements per row, we can remove items with a boolean mask:

```
In [289]: arr = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]] 
     ...: )                                                                                                     
In [290]: idx = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 6], [0, 1, 5]])                                                     
In [291]: mask = np.ones_like(arr, dtype=bool)                                                                  
In [292]: mask[np.arange(3)[:,None], idx] = False                                                               
In [293]: arr[mask]                                                                                             
Out[293]: array([0, 1, 5, 6, 0, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6])
In [294]: arr[mask].reshape(3,-1)                                                                               
Out[294]: 
array([[0, 1, 5, 6],
       [0, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 6]])
```